# How do I extend my activity's view behind the navigation bar on Android 10 and later?

Tags: android

If you open Google Calendar on a phone running Android 10 (or later, presumably), you'll see the affordance for the ability to swipe up from the bottom of the screen is still there as a grey bar, but it's rendered over the top of the activity itself.

[image: Google Calendar]

On my own app, however, this navigation bar at the bottom (if indeed that's what it is) has a grey background and my activity presumably stops at the top of it.

[image: My app]

How do I do what Google Calendar has done?

Comment: Hi @Eliot. Did you find any solution for this query? I am able to change the navigation bar color, but the example of google calendar you provided actually extends the screen.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your app theme:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

like:

```
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Nope, that hasn't made any difference, sorry.

Comment: @Eliot replace #000000 with your color's code and set this theme to your default application theme in your manifest to change status bar color, and test this: replace colorPrimaryDark with your color, to see change

Comment: Oh I see. I think you meant navigationBarColor, not statusBarColor.

Comment: Shahriyar Aghajani, can you edit your answer and I'll accept it.